# Dagger 2 scope and subcomponents

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, scope, dagger-2

I am trying to make my app better and code more maintainable using `Dagger2` I caught general idea, but still cannot figure out how scopes are managed by `Dagger2`
I injected dagger into my project (sounds funny). 
I created `ApplicationComonent` component and it works perfectly in my project.
Here is my code.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ThreadingModule.class,
        NetworkModule.class,
        DatabaseModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
        ParseModule.class,
        PreferencesSessionModule.class})

public interface ApplicationComponent {
    ActivityComponent activityComponent(ActivityModule activityModule);

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

    void inject(MainAppActivity mainAppActivity);

    void inject(MyApplication application);

    void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);

    void inject(MyService service);

    void inject(RegistrationIntentService service);
}
```

I create my component instance in `MyApplication` class like this

```
private void initializeAndInjectComponent() {
        mApplicationComponent =
                DaggerApplicationComponent
                        .builder()
                        .threadingModule(new ThreadingModule(1))
                        .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                        .networkModule(new NetworkModule(
                                MyService.API_SERVER_BASE_URL,
                                MyService.TIMEOUT))
                        .build();
        mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }
```

And I can obtain component in order to inject in in my `Activities`

```
    MyApplication application = MyApplication.get(this);
    application.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```

Everything works perfectly.

To add each method as well as module class is annotated with `@Singleton` scope, all modules related to the `ApplicationComponent`

Now I want to make dependencies better and I have seen a lot of examples with custom scopes like `@PerActivity`, `@PerFragment`. I have a lot of questions, but about this later.

So I created `ActivityComponent`

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(
        modules = {
                NetworkServiceModule.class,
                ActivityModule.class,
                PermissionModule.class
        })
public interface ActivityComponent {
    Activity activity();

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);
}
```

All modules looks like this

```
@PerActivity
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private Activity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    Activity provideActivity() {
        return this.mActivity;
    }
}
```

I have following dependencies in my `BaseActivity`

```
// Dependencies from ApplicationComponent
    @Inject
    protected ApplicationSettingsManager mApplicationSettingsManager;
    @Inject
    protected ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mPoolExecutor;
// Dependencies from ActivityComponent
    @Inject
    protected SpiceManager mSpiceManager;
    @Inject
    protected PermissionController mPermissionController;
```

And in my `onCreate()` method I am injecting as following

```
    MyApplication application = MyApplication.get(this);
    application.getApplicationComponent().activityComponent(new ActivityModule(this)).inject(this);
```

Before creating subcomponent `ActivityComponent` it was

```
   MyApplication application = MyApplication.get(this);
        application.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```

Now I got an error

```
Error:(34, 10) error: com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
BaseActivity.mSpiceManager
[injected field of type: com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager mSpiceManager]
```

I cannot figure out where is problem, what I missed.
My questions about scopes in dagger2.

Everything but `@Singleton` is ignored by Dagger 2, am I right ? 
I don't understand how life of component is managed ? I have only one idea

1. When you use `@Singleton` annotation dagger is creating object in some static pool that will exist during whole application lifecycle, and will be destroyed when JVM process (dalvik VM,ART) instance will be destroyed.
2. When you use any other annotation is just for you as developer to better maintain code, `@PerActivity`, `@PerFragment` is just custom annotation nothing more. And in case you place `@PerFragment` component in Application class it will live as long as Application lives. Am I right ?
3. So I understand this like this, if dagger finds `@Singleton` annotation it will add static reference to component when it is created first time and in case of any other annotation it won't hold reference to component.

I would be very grateful for any help with problems described above.

**UPDATE**

Thank you `David Medenjak` for great answer, I got much better understanding of `Dagger2`.

I have also just found the problem, as far as I am using separate `Activity` component now, I forgot about two lines in `ApplicationComponent` and change inejction in my `MainActivity` to `ActivityComponent` instead of `ApplicationComponent`,  so for sure it couldn't resolve dependencies from subcomponent.

```
 void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

 void inject(MainAppActivity mainAppActivity);
```

Now everything works perfectly, I like `Dagger2` and separated architecture.

Comment: I am having same issues like you. From your updated answer, I'm still not sure what to fix. Could you please share some source code so that I can get a better idea?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A bit radical, but to simplify things:
*All Scope annotations are nothing but syntactic sugar—including `@Singleton`.*

Scopes mostly just provide compile time checks. Cyclic dependencies, or errors about things that you might have missed. `@Singleton` is just like any other scope, the only difference is that it is an already existing annotation and you don't have to create it yourself. You could just use `@MySingleton` instead.

> [...] dagger is creating object in some static pool that will exists during whole application lifecycle

No. Dagger does *nothing* static. You have component objects. Those components hold your objects created by modules. If an object in a component has the scope of the component, it will only be created once in *that exact component*. If you decide to create 2 `AppComponent` objects, you will have 2 objects of each `@Singleton` annotated object, each within its component. This is why you should **keep the reference to the component.** Most implementations that I have seen or used hence keep their `AppComponent` within their  `Application`. If you do this, you can use it *like* a singleton—it is still just a POJO.

> [...]you place @PerFragment component in Application class it will live as long as Application lives.

Yes. As already covered by the paragraph above, it is just an object. Keep the reference, you keep the objects. Throw it away or create a new one and you have new objects (defined within in this component / scope). You should although *not* keep activity or fragment scoped components any place besides in activities or fragments respectively, since keeping them e.g. in your app component will most likely lead to a memory leak. (If it doesn't, you probably would not have needed the activity or fragment scope.)

> if dagger finds `@Singleton` annotation it will add static reference to component when it is created first time and in case of any other annotation it won't hold reference to component.

Again, no. Nothing static. Plain old java objects. You can have multiple `@Singleton` components with their own objects, but you probably shouldn't (Although this is what makes instrumentation testing possible / easy—just swap components.)

---

#### Your mentioned error

> SpiceManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

This means that the component you are trying to inject your object with can not find any way to produce or provide a `SpiceManager`. Make sure you provide it from your AppComponent or some other place, are not missing any annotations, etc.

Comment: Thank you for awesome explanation ! I really needed such answer, I read a lot of different articles about `Dagger2` but there were any word about scoped under the hood.

Comment: This answer demystifies a lot about Dagger 2 that can make it seem confusing. Documentation, to date, isn't brilliant, but its getting better all the time - if everyone read this answer when they start using Dagger 2 it would help them a lot.

Comment: Really great explanation!

Comment: `If an object in a component has the scope of the component, it will only be created once in that exact component. If you decide to create 2 AppComponent objects, you will have 2 objects of each @Singleton annotated object, each within its component` Super

Comment: `You should although not keep activity or fragment scoped components any place besides in activities or fragments respectively, since keeping them e.g. in your app component will most likely lead to a memory leak.` Please explain or any example.

Comment: Great asnwer, Super easy explanation. Totally agree with @MarkKeen

Comment: `If an object in a component has the scope of the component, it will only be created once in that exact component.` if that's true (and it is true), then it's not just compilation time check + syntactic sugar though!